# different types of jQuery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery

What’s the difference between $(“#foo .bar”) and $(“#foo”).find(“.bar”)?

```js
$('#foo').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('.bar').css('background-color', 'yellow');
})

$('#foo_two .bar_two').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "foo">
    <p class= 'bar' style='background: green'> Hello there</p>
</div>

<div id = 'foo_two'>
    <p class = 'bar_two' style='background: orange'> Hello there</p>
</div>
```

In the snippet, I tried to outline what I thought was the difference but seem to now not know what's going on...

Comment: In the end? Nothing. Both search for descendants of an element with the ID of foo with the class bar.

Comment: okay, thanks. so performance / browser version will not be affect by either usage?

Comment: No performance difference, really. You should also consider reading into [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: It should be noted, as Roko posted below, that your click events are assigned at different levels. If you have multiple things inside the parent, but only want the click to occur on the child, you have problems

Comment: By the way, your first question is not the same as the code sample you've given. if you use `$('#foo .bar').on('click', function(){/*...*/})` or `$('#foo').find('.bar').on('click', function(){/*...*/})`, they do the exact same thing.

Comment: thanks for clarifying everyone. it now makes sense. as demonstrated, i did not have much knowledge on this topic.

Comment: According to [this test](http://jsperf.com/difference-between-foo-bar-and-foo-find-bar), they're not exactly the same in terms of performance. It's pretty fast anyway though.

Comment: Technically, the first one should be faster since jQuery can use the native `getElementById` method instead of using Sizzle.  But you are saving only a few milliseconds and probably not worth the effort in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(){
```

means that the parent `#foo` is the click target Element

```
$('#foo_two .bar_two').on('click', function(){
```

... click on the parent `#foo_two` if you dare! http://jsfiddle.net/0qcssuue/2/

<sup>(`.bar_two` has now the click event bound to it. `#foo_two` just helped jQuery and the JS parser to find it's child `.bar_two` Element)</sup>

To conclude, the `$(this)` inside the function refers to the targeted Selector.
 In the first case it's `#foo`,
in the second it's `#foo_two .bar_two` (the `#foo_two`'s children `.bar_two`)

In your case you could **not notice the difference** cause the parent was wrapping so close the child element that every click seemed to target the same selector. Adding some padding to the parent (like in my demo) makes the difference more clear.

Comment: ahhh perfect! makes sense now. thanks Roko! (says I still have 9 minutes to accept...)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is in which object you are attaching the listener for click event.
For case:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(){
  $(this).find('.bar').css('background-color', 'yellow');
})
```

You are attaching the listener to the *#foo* object.

For case:

```
$('#foo_two .bar_two').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```

You are attaching the listener to the *#foo_two .bar_two* object

I adjust your fiddle to show the difference. Green label changes when you click de **div** element but orange label changes when you click the **p** element

http://jsfiddle.net/0qcssuue/3/